# confluent kafka hdfs connector hive

Tags: hive, hdfs, apache-kafka, connector, confluent-platform

I am using the confluent to import data from kafka to hive, trying to do the same thing as this: [Bucket records based on time(kafka-hdfs-connector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036507/bucket-records-based-on-timekafka-hdfs-connector/41257922#41257922)

my sink config is like this:

```
{
    "name":"yangfeiran_hive_sink_9",
    "config":{
        "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
        "topics":"peoplet_people_1000",
        "name":"yangfeiran_hive_sink_9",
        "tasks.max":"1",
        "hdfs.url":"hdfs://master:8020",
        "flush.size":"3",
        "partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
        "partition.duration.ms":"300000",
        "path.format":"'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH/'minute'=mm/",
        "locale":"en",
        "logs.dir":"/tmp/yangfeiran",
        "topics.dir":"/tmp/yangfeiran",
        "hive.integration":"true",
        "hive.metastore.uris":"thrift://master:9083",
        "schema.compatibility":"BACKWARD",
        "hive.database":"yangfeiran",
        "timezone": "UTC",
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, I can see that data is in the hdfs, the table is created in the hive, except when I am using "select * from yang" to check if the data is already in hive.

It prints the error:

FAILED: SemanticException Unable to determine if hdfs://master:8020/tmp/yangfeiran/peoplet_people_1000 is encrypted: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://master:8020/tmp/yangfeiran/peoplet_people_1000, expected: hdfs://nsstargate

How to solve this problem?

Feiran

Comment: Is your hdfs in HA mode?

Comment: yes, it is, should I forbidden that?

Comment: yes, try to omit port number in url to hdfs.

Comment: Thanks bro, it works. Brove!

Comment: However, the production environment need us to apply the HA mode, is there a way of coexistence?

Comment: I think the only way is to implement your own ParquetWriter.

Comment: Cheers mate, I will try. You made my day!

Comment: Your welcome! BTW, there is pull request  for this issue. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/pull/90

Comment: I worked it out, by adding "hive.conf.dir": "/etc/hive/conf".

Comment: Following this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/confluent-platform/wKa6gC32Gwo/6kcHOJBkKAAJ